# Border to the input field in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need a border to the input element like the image below:

[image]

But am getting a different result with the following code. Can someone help me to get this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .input-number{
   width: 25px !important;
   margin: 0 5px;
   font-size: 25px;
   border-bottom:2px solid #000;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:150px;padding:50px;">
  <input type="text" class="input-number" value="0"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you add `border: none;` before the `border-bottom:` you will get only the bottom border. But it not as same as the image you provided. But try :)

Comment: Are you referring to the botton border only or with the small border of left and right?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom border box as follows:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="input-number" value="0"/>
<div class="borderbox"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-number {
    width: 25px !important;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.input-number:focus {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
.borderbox {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  width: 30px;
  height:10px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

Codepen link for reference:
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/vdeRWw